# Dubbio sulla parola “correggia”

Tags: word-meaning

Tempo fa ho letto un libro dove c’era scritto:

> Valentina si appiattì a terra, sfiorò l’ammattonato del pavimento saltando a rana tra le gambe delle sorelle e, raggiunta la scala a piuoli dell’abbaino, ci si arrampicò svelta come una gatta, con il binocolo nero che le ciondolava sulle reni, appeso al collo con la lunga **correggia** di pelle.

Visto che per me questa parola  era nuova, ho cercato e ho trovato che è una cinta, forse per cavalli. Sino a qui è tutto chiaro.
Però, a volte, parlando, capita di sentire delle varianti.

Non riesco a capire se siano forme dialettali con diversi significati.

Ecco alcuni esempi che sento e leggo:

> Annabelle ruppe la sureggia della borsa.

Interpretazione: Ha rotto il manico della borsa.

> Donne e scorregge scappano.

Interpretazione: le donne scappano come anche le briglie dei cavalli.

> La vita è breve come la scoreggia di una farfalla.

Interpretazione: la vita è breve come le antenne delle farfalle (ho molti problemi su questa).

> Sono tre, no quattro! Mi correggia lei se sbaglio.

Interpretazione: non ho idea...

A volte gli amici miei hanno detto:

> Ho tirato una scureggia fortissima e il gatto si è svegliato.

Interpretazione: ha lanciato qualcosa e ha fatto svegliare il gatto.

**Q: qual è il significato più corretto di “correggia”? Ha significato dilettale? “Correggia”, “scorreggia”, “scureggia”, “corregga” hanno lo stesso significato?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Non sono assolutamente espressioni dialettali: rientrano infatti nella lingua  Italiana.

Una ‘correggia’, come più o meno hai già accennato, è una striscia, solitamente di cuoio, usata per avvicinare due oggetti. Può anche voler dire ‘cinghia’ o,  semplicemente, “striscia di pelle”. In antichità veniva anche chiamata ‘scorreggia’.

Oggi ‘[scorreggia](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scoreggia_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/)’  vuol dire ‘flatulenza’, “emissione rumorosa di gas intestinali dall'ano”, idem ‘scureggia’, versione popolare del termine. Ovviamente ‘correggia’  in questo caso è sinonimo di ‘scorreggia’ ([guarda qua](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ricerca/correggia/) per ulteriori chiarimenti).

Per quanto riguarda le frasi che hai scritto, posso dirti che:

> Annabelle ruppe la sureggia della borsa.

Sebbene possiamo usare ‘scorreggia’come sinonimo di ‘correggia’, non mi risulta valga lo stesso per ‘scureggia’. Suppongo quindi o che tu abbia fatto un errore di battitura, oppure che sia sbagliata la frase che hai letto (o semplicemente che io sia stata informata in modo errato). Ad ogni modo, se il termine fosse giusto, la tua interpretazione sarebbe corretta: la correggia di una borsa può, infatti, essere il suo manico.

> Donne e scorregge scappano.

Si tratta di una citazione di Stefano Benni : “Donne e scoregge scappano anche se non vuoi”. Significa semplicemente che nonostante uno non voglia farsele scappare, le donne e le flatulenze scappano: infatti una donna può abbandonare un uomo senza che quest’ultimo voglia e una flatulenza può scappare…

> La vita è breve come la scoreggia di una farfalla.

Anche qua si parla di flatulenze. Non credo siano necessarie ulteriori spiegazioni.

> Sono tre, no quattro! Mi correggia lei se sbaglio.

Qua sono fortemente convinta che tu abbia sbagliato a scrivere o che abbia capito male. Se così non fosse la frase non avrebbe senso. Suppongo volessi dire ‘corregga’ che è voce del verbo *[correggere](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/correggere/)*.

> Ho tirato una scureggia fortissima e il gatto si è svegliato.

Sempre come prima, il tuo amico ha emesso una flatulenza talmente rumorosa da svegliare il gatto. Non ha tirato niente di fisico.

Comment: Il mio sospetto è che *correggia* in "Mi corregia se sbaglio" sia un errore intenzionale, a motivi umoristici (cfr. la famosa citazione di papa Giovanni Paolo II ["se sbaglio mi corrigerete"](https://youtu.be/XGutOoon7xE?t=106), dove la comicità è probabilmente non intenzionale, ma di grande effetto)

Comment: @DenisNardin hai ragione, è possibile

Comment: @DenisNardin no, ho sbagliato di scrivere, ha ragione Mary, grazie